# How to display value of encoded string on a PHP generated page?

Tags: php

Using `htmlspecialchars($str)` we get an encoded string. 
When including this string on a page, User sees the string "as it was typed in".
Page source shows that the string is actually encoded to `&quot;` etc...

That's all working fine.

How would I display the encoded string to the User so that he sees exactly how it was was encoded? I would prefer not to use textarea, if possible.

... there seems to be some challenge in understanding the question. Let's cook up a simple example.

```
$encodedString = htmlspecialchars(userInput:My favourite quote: "I can resist everything except temptation.");
$userMessage = 'You\'ve entered <'.$encodedString.'>';
echo $userMessage;
```

I want the User to see `You've entered <My favourite quote: &quot;I can resist everything except temptation.&quot;>`.

This silly example shows the problem very well. I don't want to send $userMessage to htmlspecialchars because it will also touch my own '<' and '>'.

So again, the question is: can I `echo $userMessage;` to the screen so that User sees exactly the string that I've constructed?

Comment: @jackn yes you would have to encode the ampersand like you suggested.

Comment: `echo htmlspecialchars(htmlspecialchars('"'));` - doesn't work?  `&amp;quot;`  [Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/08cb26f4f4cb2c095a423a87f02cbcb516c64164)

Comment: By saying 'this page', I mean that I ran into my own issue trying to describe the problem here... See the encoded double quotes. I used the magic quotes to denote code and it showed exactly what I want. So I then went into the page source to see how stackoverflow was able to handle it.

Comment: I get it. I would like to avoid double encoding it, though. If possible. I need more room to explain, so I'll update the question.

Comment: Ok, you just double encode it.  Be careful how you save it, and allow them to edit it etc.  You don't want to encode in {n} times when they save.  That's why they say to do it on output/display only....

Comment: btw you should be saving the raw text when the user submits it. Then encode it when you display the text on the website.

Comment: `avoid double encoding it` the only way to do that is to encode it yourself and that is **not** something you want to do.  I mean you could encode it once and then `str_replace('&', '&amp;', htmlspecialchars('"'))` but what's the difference at that point.

Comment: "I also append my own parts to this string that I do not want to be encoded" -> what difference does it make exactly? You can concatenate normal (single-encoded) strings to double-encoded strings if need be. Please provide more details and an example.

Comment: I can append but I want to display the produced string to the User, exactly as it is.

Answer (score 2):

> I see this page uses double encoding of some sort: `<code>&amp;quot;</code>`. Is this the way to do it?

First, you should not confuse the code that you *enter* into a form post with the code that is used to *output* that page. When you enter code on this site, some Javascript runs as you type to render what you you've typed into HTML markup which is immediately displayed in your browser. This behavior took blood, sweat, and tears to cook up by some developer and probably has no bearing on what you want to happen on *your* site. So let's ignore it for now.

The proper approach to getting things displayed on *your* site would likely depend on whether you have any frameworks you are using, etc., but the basic question you appear to be asking is how to show the input and output of php's [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) function.

> Is it possible to avoid double encoding?

It's funny you ask this because you probably *do* want to double-encode text to get the result you are asking for.  We are talking about several code concepts here. The first is your plan text. Maybe something like this:

`here is my "plaintext", OK?`

If you call htmlspecialchars on that in a PHP function like this:

```php
$str = 'here is my "plaintext", OK?';
echo $str . "<br>\n";
echo htmlspecialchars($str) . "<br>\n";
```

If you run this PHP code from the command line, you see its text output like this:

```
here is my "plaintext", OK?<br>
here is my &quot;plaintext&quot;, OK?<br>
```

If you run that PHP code on a web server and view the result in a web browser, your web browser is reading that exact same text, but it **renders the output as HTML** so it displays like so:

```
here is my "plaintext", OK?
here is my "plaintext", OK?
```

If you choose the *view source* option in our browser, you'll see the exact same output as you did when you ran it from the command line.

Now, if you want this code to display the htmlspecialchars output in a browser, you have a couple of options. You can send a content-type header that says the output should be interpreted as plaintext:

```php
$str = 'here is my "plaintext", OK?';

// tells the browser not to parse the code as HTML
header("content-type: text/plain");

echo $str . "<br>\n";
echo htmlspecialchars($str) . "<br>\n";
```

OR you can double-encode the string by calling htmlspecialchars on it more than once. Try running this code and see what you get for output:

```php
$str = 'here is my "plaintext", OK?';
echo $str . "<br>\n";
echo htmlspecialchars($str) . "<br>\n";
echo htmlspecialchars(htmlspecialchars($str)) . "<br>\n";
```

If you run it from the command-line, the output looks like this:

```
here is my "plaintext", OK?<br>
here is my &quot;plaintext&quot;, OK?<br>
here is my &amp;quot;plaintext&amp;quot;, OK?<br>
```

That code, displayed in a browser, looks like this:

```
here is my "plaintext", OK?
here is my "plaintext", OK?
here is my &quot;plaintext&quot;, OK?
```